# Converting file:/// image to base64 with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, base64

Here's my code to convert a normal image to base64:

```
var c = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "file:///" + contact.photos[0].value;
ctx.drawImage(img, 100, 100);
console.log(c.toDataURL());
```

However, this outputs an empty image.  The `contact.photos[0].value` variable is from the Cordova Contacts Plugin, in which all contact photos on iOS are represented as local URLs.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Wait for the image to load (hopefully that helps). Use `img.onload = function () { ctx.drawImage(img, 100, 100); };` right before setting the `src` property

Comment: Nope, this still isn't working.

Comment: Is this page being loaded as `file://` or as `http(s)://`?

Comment: It's not a page, it's an image, and is loaded with file:///

Comment: The JavaScript is loaded on a page - how that page served? I don't believe `http(s)://` has access to `file://` is my point

Comment: Ah, I get it.  I'm using Angular with a Cordova app.